# Recurring contribution that ends after 10 payments

Tags: recurring-contributions

Using Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 5.37.2 / CiviCRM Stripe 6.6.

We would like to run a recurring contribution campaign where the recurring contributions end after 10 contributions.  Essentially we are offering a course that we wish for people to pay in monthly increments rather than all at once.

Is there a way to set a recurring contribution to end after X contributions?

I believe this is possible with webform-civicrm (right?) but what about with vanilla CiviCRM contribution pages?  Or with CiviCRM+CiviRules?  We are considering migrating to Wordpress so I'm seeking options that use vanilla CiviCRM if possible.

We do have the ca.civicrm.contributionrecur extension, which allows us to force a contribution page to only accept recurring contributions, so that part is handled.  What I need is an automated way to stop the contributions.

Thank you so much!

Update: Webform could make this work, but not with Stripe.  Webform and Stripe combine with this error: "Unable to complete payment! Missing paymentMethodID".  See [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/290) for status.

Comment: Did you try setting installments to 10 via Jquery or phpcode?

Comment: @PradeepNayak I don't know how to do that.  Will search for some sample jquery code to do this.  Thank you for the suggestion.